Board is not selected (Arduino with CLion)
I am looking to use CLion instead of the Arduino IDE to run code on my ESP32 (It is a custom one using the ESP32-S3 chip). I added the boards.txt file that is used in the Arduino IDE to get the correct board (ESP32-S3 Dev Module). However, whoever I try to make a new sketch, the create button is disabled and I see "Board is not selected" at the bottom (see screenshot). What am I supposed to do? I was able to create a new sketch previously before I downloaded the Legacy Arduino IDE for the Arduino SDK. I am on an M1 Pro mac if that helps.
FYI I need to use Arduino not PlatformIO because the club uses it and I don't want to try anything different.

